# Why did Jacob need to walk into the rain to get his memory erased?

Tags: plot-explanation, fantastic-beasts, fantastic-beasts-where-to-find-them

At the end of *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*, Newt helps to *obliviate* all *No-majs* by using Swooping evil's venom.
Somehow, I don't understand why Jacob only forgets everything he has done together with Newt when he's walking into the rain. There's a guy shown in the shower who seems to lose his memory, too and he's not standing outside.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rain water contaminates the water in the pipelines and/or overhead storage tanks of the buildings in the city.

As you mentioned, a guy in the shower loses his memory. There is also a shot of a woman drinking from a tap who also loses her memory.

Observational deduction and I don't have any links confirming this.

Answer (score -1):

Also, they could've easily obliviated him instead of making him walk into the rain, but I think that wasn't how it was shown because that would mean that the characters *proactively* wipe his memory, and I think none of them had the heart to do that. Which is why making him walk into the rain was possibly a kinder thing to do.

Comment: This does not answer the actual question

Comment: At face value, this looks like a fine Doylist answer.